# Could twin planets exist and share the same orbit?

Tags: orbit, planet

Could there be a stable orbit shared by two planets with the same mass and density? Regardless of whether the formation of such system is possible or not.

For example, if Earth and Venus could have the same orbit around the sun, but each planet in the opposite side of the orbit, would that orbit be stable?

Comment: Are you talking about a binary/double planet or some other configuration?

Comment: @called2voyage I added an example using Earth and Venus, thanks for the comment.

Comment: *"For example, if Earth and Venus could have the same orbit around the sun, but each planet in the opposite side of the orbit.."*  See also the [Lagrangian point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_point)(s)..

Comment: Strictly technically, by current International Astronomical Union's (IAU) definition of a planet (Resolution 5A), no. Co-orbital planet-sized bodies within the Solar system would fail the _cleared the neighbourhood around its orbit_ requirement. And outside of the Solar system, according to IAU's rationale, planets don't even exist, since they're not _in orbit around the Sun_.

Comment: Similar question on physics.SE: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/25978/two-planets-in-same-orbit-not-planets

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The term for bodies sharing an orbit in this manner is [co-orbital configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Co-orbital_configuration). It is technically possible for two objects of planetary size to share an orbit like this, and we may have even found [an example](https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn20160-two-planets-found-sharing-one-orbit/) in an extrasolar system.

It is speculated that early in Earth's history that it shared an orbit with a Mars-sized planet named [Theia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theia_%28planet%29) which later collided with Earth to produce the Moon.

Comment: Note that the the update at the top of that linked article suggests the discovery to be in error. Though you _did_ say "may".

Answer (score 23):

Saturn has co-orbital moons, [Epimetheus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epimetheus_%28moon%29) and [Janus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Janus_%28moon%29). They orbit in the same direction and swap orbits approximately every four years as the inner body catches up with the outer body.

Answer (score 8):

I believe the two bodies could be orbiting a central bodies at the stable [Lagrange points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_point). Planet A would be at Planet B's L4 Lagrange point, and Planet B would be at Planet A's L5 point.

[image: Lagrange Points]

<sub>from Wikipedia</sub>

Comment: Would an orbit containing two bodies of equal mass even have the same lagrange points? The math only works because there's nothing of non-negligible mass in the neighborhood.

Comment: @Random832 That question has been on my mind for the last couple of days. I was thinking about asking it as a question on its own. But I am unsure whether here or physics is the best place to ask it.

Comment: @Random832 That's a good point, it probably wouldn't have the same lagrange points. I think you're right that the third body is assumed to have negligible mass.