# Could two planet-like objects be created-as or form a binary pair that orbits something else?

Tags: orbit, planet

Could two identical or slightly different planets (or planet-like objects if you want to be pedantic) form a binary pair that then orbit some other larger gravitic object (like a star)?

I was inspired by [Could twin planets exist and share the same orbit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/12189/could-twin-planets-exist-and-share-the-same-orbit) which I thought initially was asking the question I'm asking, but wasn't.

Comment: Does Pluto-Charon qualify for your question? Charon's diameter is about half Pluto's, and 1/10 the mass. Their orbital center is outside of Pluto, and they orbit the sun.

Answer (score 1):

It appears what you are describing is a double planet.  There are no examples that we know of where the two planets are practically identical, but I do not believe there is anything prohibiting such an occurrence.

See 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_planet

Comment: You really should mention Pluto/ Charon, they are a double planet by most standards (Or double dwarf planet, at least...)